# Access Grouping Across Rows by criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, transpose

I have the table below and am trying to group across rows based on an id. I want access to return all cases where type contains an S and A for the same id (a19), but not return instances where S or A exist without each other (a22 & a33).

What is the easiest way to do this?

```
+---+----+--------------+
|id |type|    text      |
+---+----+--------------+
 a19   S     S1
 a19   A     A1
 a19   A     A1
 a22   Y     A1
 a33   S     S1
+---+----+--------------+
```

Comment: I don't think you want grouping. I think you will need to use a self join but I'm not exactly sure how to do it. I retagged it so that one of the SQL experts here can help you out. Also, the table you are shoing here has duplicate records (2nd and 3rd records). I hope this was just a typo, or maybe you aren't showing all fields here.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a query that returns ALL ids that have both A and S types:

```
SELECT subQuery.id
FROM (SELECT group_table.id
FROM group_table
WHERE (((group_table.type) IN ("A","S")))
GROUP BY group_table.id, group_table.type)  AS subQuery
GROUP BY subQuery.id
HAVING Count(subQuery.id) = 2
```

You can make it somewhat flexible by replacing **"...IN ("A", "S")..."** with something like **"SELECT FilterType FROM FilterTable"** and changing **"...Count(subQuery.id) = 2..."** to e.g. **"...Count(subQuery.id) = SELECT COUNT(FilterType) FROM FilterTable..."**